# Soilgrids REST API Not Working: 504 Error

Tags: soilgrids

For the last month or so, whenever I have tried calling the REST API (at https://rest.isric.org/soilgrids/v2.0/properties/query) or even visiting the docs page at https://rest.isric.org/soilgrids/v2.0/docs, I have been getting a 504 Gateway Time-out error. Is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: you need to reach out to  ISRIC - World Soil Information https://www.isric.org/contact-us

Comment: data is still available via https://files.isric.org/

Answer (score 1):

SoilGrids REST API is a complementary service ISRIC-World Soil information provides to access Soilgrids. It is still under active development (beta stage). Occasional issues and downtimes may occur.
For the moment, in order to maintain optimal performance of our API, our Fair Use Policy is defined as 5 API calls per 1 minute period.
More info on alternative ways to access Soilgrids can be found [in the FAQ page of Soilgrids](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_access_SoilGrids)